# Determining the sign of the derivative of a system of linear equations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have the following system of $2 \times n$ linear equations:
\begin{align*}
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 2b & (1+\kappa_{12})a_{12} & \cdots & (1+\kappa_{1n})a_{1n}\\
  (1+\kappa_{21})a_{12} & 2b  & \cdots & (1+\kappa_{2n})a_{2n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
 (1+\kappa_{n1})a_{1n} &  (1+\kappa_{n2})a_{2n}& \cdots& 2b
 \end{bmatrix}}_{:=\mathbf{K_a}}
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 q_1\\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ q_n
 \end{bmatrix}}_{:=\mathbf{q}}
 &
 =(A-\bar{c})\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\1\\ \vdots \\ 1
 \end{bmatrix}+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \beta_{12} & \cdots & \beta_{1n}\\
 \beta_{12} & 1  & \cdots & \beta_{2n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
 \beta_{1n} & \beta_{2n}& \cdots& 1
 \end{bmatrix}}_{:=\mathbf{B}}
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n
 \end{bmatrix}}_{:=\mathbf{x}}
 \\
 \frac{1}{\gamma}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \kappa_{12}\beta_{12} & \cdots & \kappa_{1n}\beta_{1n}\\
 \kappa_{21}\beta_{12} & 1  & \cdots & \kappa_{2n}\beta_{2n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
 \kappa_{n1}\beta_{1n} & \kappa_{n2}\beta_{2n}& \cdots& 1
 \end{bmatrix}}_{:=\mathbf{K_\beta}}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 q_1\\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ q_n
 \end{bmatrix}
 &
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $b > a_{ij} \geq 0$, $0 \leq \kappa_{ij} \leq 1$, $A - \bar{c} > 0$, $x_{i} > 0$, $q_{i} > 0$, and $i = 1,2,...,n$.

Plugging the second system of first-order conditions into the first yields the vector $\mathbf{x^*}$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{x^*} =  \begin{bmatrix}
 x^*_1\\x^*_2\\ \vdots \\ x^*_n
 \end{bmatrix}
 = (A - \bar{c})
 \left[
 \gamma \mathbf{K_a}\mathbf{K_\beta}^{-1}-\mathbf{B}\right]^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{1}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector of ones.

**I would now like to show under which conditions the element $x^{*}_{1}$ increases when all $\kappa_{1j}$ for $j = 2,3,...,n$ increase.**

Note that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ and $\beta_{ij} = \beta_{ji}$ in the above equations, but $\kappa_{ij} \neq \kappa_{ji}$. If it makes the problem easier, it's perfectly fine to assume symmetry such that $\kappa_{ij} = \kappa_{ji}$.

Maybe it's also easier to show under which conditions $x^{*}_{i}$ increases when $\kappa_{ij}$ (i.e., just one of all those $\kappa_{ij}$) increases:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x_{i}^{*}}{\partial \kappa_{ij}} > 0
\end{align}

---

In the symmetric case where $a_{ij} = a$, $\beta_{ij} = \beta$, and $\kappa_{ij} = \kappa$ this is straightforward. Because $x^{*}_{i} = x^{*}$ and $q^{*}_{i} = q^{*}$ and hence

\begin{align}
q^{*} &= \frac{A - \bar{c}}{2b + a(n-1)(1+\kappa) - \frac{\tau B}{\gamma}} \\
x^{*} &= \frac{\tau}{\gamma} q^{*}
\end{align}
where $\tau = 1 + \kappa \beta(n-1)$ and $B=1+\beta(n-1)$.

Therefore, $\frac{\partial x^{*}}{\partial \kappa} > 0$ if $\beta > \frac{a}{2b+a(n-1)}$.